# Unity - Make something move but stop when it reaches a certain position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So here is my code: (Im new and I know if this is incorrect!) BTW this is for Unity

```
void Update () {
   if (Input.GetButtonDown("Left"))
   {
       Transform.position xPrevPos yPrevPos
       rb.velocity = new Vector2(horzMove, 0) * speed;
       if(Transform.position == x + 5f)
       {
           ## DO SOMETHING ##
       }
   }
}
```

So what I want it to do is to first check if the left button is pressed, then remember the current position, then start the movement, then if it reaches the position I want it stops and listens for another button to be pressed. The reason why I write x + 5f is because I want it to move that distance to the left before it stops

Hope you understand!

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Please create a [mcve] and explain what the problem is. (Hint: you probably want to store a "start" position instead of just the position on the previous frame)

Comment: i said that the code was incorrect, but i described what i need in the text field below the code

Comment: What  do you have in mind a 2D or a 3D game? And this movement should be repetitive? like a platform moving from right to left all the time, or more like an enemy chasing you that stops when it reachs an area or point?

Comment: yes its 2048 game and its 2d, altho i wanted to start with 1 tile first and then make the rest, hope that helps

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre i think i understand and i will give you best answer if you make a short description and also explain why you use vector 3 when its a 2d game. Just a short comment or something. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is taken from one of the tutorials in the official Unity website. It´s a spaceship controller. You set some boundaries in the inspector, so the player can´t move the spaceship beyond those boundaries

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class Boundary
{
    public float xMin, xMax, zMin, zMax;
}

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public variables you can modify from the inspector
    public float speed;
    public float tilt;
    public Boundary boundary;

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        //To read the inputs of the player. The Horizontal and Vertical axis
        //Are defined in the Editor, Settings Manager, Input Manager.
        //You can change that for your own inputs like:
        //Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Enter) or key you want to use
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        //Creates a VEctor3D with the inputs and applies the movement
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rigidbody.velocity = movement * speed;

        //This part keeps the spaceship inside the boundary you passed as parameter
        rigidbody.position = new Vector3 
        (
            Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax), 
            0.0f, 
            Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
        );

        //This part is just to make the spaceship tilt to one side or 
        //another to make it more realistic
        rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0.0f, rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt);
    }
}
```

And if you are totally new, I would recommend you to start watching all or at least some of theses tutorials before start developing your own ideas. It will make everything easier for you.

https://unity3d.com/es/earn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/moving-the-player?playlist=17147

And the tutorials: https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials

**Edit**: To your question why do they use Vector3 in a 2D Game:

Basically even if you are developing a 2D game, the Engine has a 3 dimensional space, so if you define a Vector2 it will be casted to a Vector3 (then giving a 0 value to the third dimension). So in the tutorial they define a Vector3 which will have a 0 value in the y coordinate.